# compiling cddplus on linux

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

I hope this is not offtopic for a programming Q&A forum, but I have troubles compiling this program, which is very important for me.

http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/cdd_home/
and from there the newest cdd+-077a.tar.gz...

a simple `make all` (like the README suggests) yields:

```
g++ -O3 -I -I/usr/local/include -I. -DGMP -DRATIONAL -c -o cdd_r.o cdd.C
In file included from ./Rational.h:19:0,
             from cddtype.h:16,
             from cdd.C:38:
./Integer.h:779:28: Fehler: »INT_MAX« wurde in diesem Gültigkeitsbereich nicht definiert
./Integer.h:780:30: Fehler: »INT_MAX« wurde in diesem Gültigkeitsbereich nicht definiert
In file included from cddtype.h:16:0,
             from cdd.C:38:
./Rational.h: In Funktion »std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&      operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const Rational&)«:
./Rational.h:1181:35: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »strlen«, die von einem  Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »strlen« verfügbar sein muss [- fpermissive]
./Rational.h:1181:35: Anmerkung: (mit »-fpermissive« wird G++ den Code akzeptieren, aber die Verwendung eines nicht deklarierten Namens ist veraltet)
cdd.C: In Funktion »void DDEnumerate(std::ostream&, std::ostream&)«:
cdd.C:197:49: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:204:55: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:211:49: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:219:55: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C: In Funktion »void DDRowDecomposition(std::ostream&, std::ostream&)«:
cdd.C:260:53: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:301:47: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:308:53: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:315:47: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C: In Funktion »void PreProjection(std::ostream&, std::ostream&)«:
cdd.C:356:69: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:422:49: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:429:55: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:436:49: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C: In Funktion »void PostAnalysisMain(std::ifstream&, std::ostream&)«:
cdd.C:522:49: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:529:55: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:536:49: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:544:55: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C: In Funktion »int main(int, char**)«:
cdd.C:794:39: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:797:56: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
cdd.C:806:45: Warnung: veraltete Konvertierung von Zeichenkettenkonstante in »char*« [-Wwrite-strings]
make: *** [cdd_r.o] Fehler 1
```

what does that mean? Is the file itself corrupt (I highly doubt that) is my setup wrong (I'm running Ubuntu 13.04) or is there anything else I'm not aware of?

I'd really appreciate it, if anybody could point me in the right direction...

Comment: My guess is, it's just not very portable code, and it is dependent on some nonstandard compiler behaviour.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some headers. For example, `INT_MAX` is defined in `<stdint.h>` in C and in `<cstdint>` in C++.

Comment: yeah you're probably right, but the file cstdint exists on my computer in `/usr/include/c++/4.7/cstdint` which is the compiler I'm using to compile this whole thing. So the problem seems to be in the makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem as follows:

First: add the following at the begin of Integer.h:

```
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#include <stdint.h>`
```

Second:

Replace `INT_MAX` with `INT32_MAX` (this is at line 779 and 780) because, in stdint.h (usr/include), just define `INT32_MAX` with no `INT_MAX`.

Above change may just solve the first problem, which is about `INT_MAX`.

After this, you will encounter the problem with `strlen` and `memcopy`, then you can solve this by adding "string.h", into the related file, maybe Rational.h and others,I forgot.